# Clojure Newbie - Namespace troubles

Tags: clojure

I'm learning Clojure and so far I can't make sense of this little conundrum which I'm sure is ridiculously basic.

I have this file :

```
(ns cloapp.core
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
  [& args]
  (println "Hello, World!")
  (println "Well Hi there, im a string !")
  (println "Why wont this work !")
  (myFunc "Hiya"))

(defn myFunc [aVar]
    (println aVar))
```

If I try and run this with,

```
lein run
```

It complains and says,

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve symbol: myFunc in this context
```

But if I remove the call to myFunc from main and do,

```
lein repl
cloapp.core=> (myFunc "Hiya !")
Hiya !
nil
cloapp.core=>
```

Then I can call it.  Why is this ? I'm assuming it's something to do with the namespace but reading up on it I can't work it out.

A

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The myFunc symbol has not been defined yet, so main can't find it. If you move the definition of myFunc above main then it will work.

Comment: Interesting, that does indeed work.  Where can I read about this ?  Is there an equivalent of forward declaration ?

Comment: You can use 'declare' to create forward-declarations: (declare myFunc).  Also note that camel case isn't conventional with clojure function names, dashes are conventional.

Comment: These links may shed some light as to why:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/clojure/w0GIdSCNieE
and
http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2467359